# Can I send keyboard input from SSH to an app on OSX?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have XBMC on my Mac Mini as a media centre.  When in a search dialogue etc on XBMC, can I type into it via the SSH session to the mac that I already have open on my laptop?

Something like

```
echo 'bar' > /dev/keyboard
```

?

Comment: Use synergy: http://synergy-foss.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do it with AppleScript if the focus is set right (i.e. the cursor is in the search box)

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "my search terms" & return'
```

If the focus is not set on the other end, you would have to add some other commands to make it so....

EDIT: I have just tested this successfully on two remote machines (running 10.6 and 10.8) with the Safari search box. You may need to enable "Remote Management" or "Remote Apple Events" in the Sharing preference panel to get the permission to do this.

Comment: I get this error: "An error of type -10810 has occurred.", and when I check system.log I see 

com.apple.launchd.peruser.0[319]: Background: Bug: 12F45: launchd + 80370 [7DCC9489-2DF5-3807-83FA-EF5666EE8078]: 0x0

com.apple.launchd.peruser.0[319]: Background: This API can only be used by a process running within an Aqua session.


Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check Sharing settings and make sure Remote Management is turned on? I have read that Remote Apple Events will also allow it, but I was able to get it to work without having that turned on. Also, what version of OSX are you running? Sandboxed apps might not be so friendly.

Comment: Turned both of those on.  Still no dice, same errors.  Mountain Lion.

Comment: @Codemonkey - I greatly appreciate the "accept" but don't feel compelled to do so if it didn't solve your problem. Maybe someone else will know why it works for some systems and not others. (Or did it work?)

Answer (score 0):

why not use your smartphone as xmbc remote?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.android.remote

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Official_XBMC_Remote/iOS

Comment: Yeah, I do do that at the moment, I was just wondering if this was possible, and once I thought about it I wanted to find out how to do it... I feel it must be possible :)

Comment: using the webinterface could work, http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Web_interface